# need to call a method in javascript when triangle like symbol next to more items is clicked in the Sharepoint calendar

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I have used `JavaScript` to color code my SharePoint calendar.

In that script, I have to call method `ColourCalendar()` when "more items" is clicked.

```
$('.ms-cal-nav').attr('href', 'javascript:ColourCalendar();');
```

The above line is working only for "n more items" link. But when I click on the triangle like symbol next to "more items" link, it is not working.[Attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JTs6g.png)

1 more item

How can I call this method when the image in `href` is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what button you are referring to but I believe you are accessing the sorrounding `<td>`?
 This example is based on the "change year" or the arrow to the right in a calendar view.

`$('.ms-pagearrow-right-icon')` is the "triangle image" that changes year.
To be able to set href I have to.

```
$('.ms-pagearrow-right-icon').parent().attr('href', 'javascript:ColourCalendar();')
```

The `.parent()`gets the `<a>` element and so you can set the attribute.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The image that I am referring not the one that changes year. It sits just before 1more item, 2 more item links.                                                                                                        <a href="javascript:ColourCalendar();" class="ms-cal-nav" evtid="expand_collapse"><img border="0" src="/_layouts/images/expandbttn.gif" width="9" height="7">1 more item</a>

Comment: Ok, if that html is correct you should be able to use your code.  Are you trying to set this in $(document).ready? 
Try to use: _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("setButton");
function setButton () { $('.ms-cal-nav').attr('href', 'javascript:ColourCalendar();'); }

Comment: @ Simon, I tried adding the code you suggested. But it is also working for only the text "n more items". I have figured out solution. I will post. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I got this to work by adding below code.

```
            if ( $('.ms-acal-ctrlitem').attr('_expand') == 'collapse' ) {
                $('.ms-cal-nav').addClass('collapse-tag');
            } else {
                $('.ms-cal-nav').addClass('expand-tag');
            }
```

In Css, I have added below lines.

```
    .ms-cal-nav img, .ms-acal-ctrlitem a img {display: none;}.ms-cal-nav.collapse-tag {background: url(http://sharepoint/_layouts/images/collapsebttn.gif) no-repeat 0 3px;padding-left:10px;} .ms-cal-nav.expand-tag {background: url(http://sharepoint/_layouts/images/expandbttn.gif) no-repeat 0 3px;padding-left:10px;}
```